# Creating Set-Up ICON only once

Tags: icons, inno-setup

I want to create a set-up ICON for my application, only if the application has not been previously installed.

Is it possible to check for the existence of a registry item, and create set-up ICON if not in registry.

I have already created the registry item on during the installation, so upon any subsequent installs the item would be there.

Pascal is not my strong suit so any specific assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you deploy your application with a setup which has the same `AppId` as the previously installed one, then it would be taken as an upgrade, which should not create additional icon for your application, so there should not be needed to do anything. But if you really want to conditionally install an `[Icons]` entry depending on a certain registry key existance, then you might use something [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/wUwpBwyw).

Comment: TLama,  thank you for your very prompt reply, your code works flawlessly.  Now I just need to invert the value for the "InstallIcon" since I only want to create the ICON if Registry Key is NOT present.

Comment: That's easy. Instead of `Check: InstallIcon;` write `Check: not InstallIcon;`.

Comment: TLama that is Perfect,